# PHP Issue with Email Form

Tags: php, email

I have used this site before with great success and I am having a similar issue with a php email form. I tried to copy from the previous form that the guys on this site were extremely helpful in getting to work the way I wanted, but for some reason or another it won't send the form. I am sure that it is a silly oversight, but would appreciate a second set of eyes.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$state = 0;
// check to see if verificaton code was correct
if(md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']){
// if verification code was correct send the message and show this page
mail("myemailaddress@hotmail.com", 'Website Inquiry: '.$subject, "\n".$comments." 
\n\n".$name."\n\n".$company."\n\n".$email."\n\n".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n\n".'InterestedIn: '.$InterestedIn, "\n\n".'ContactMethod: '.$ContactMethod,"From: $email");
// delete the cookie so it cannot sent again by refreshing this page
setcookie('tntcon','');
$state = 2;
} else if(isset($message) and $message!=""){
// if verification code was incorrect then return to contact page and show error
$state = 1;
}

if ($state == 0) {  ?>
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" 

onsubmit="MM_validateForm('email','','RisEmail','name','','R','verif_box','','R')

;return document.MM_returnValue">

 <p><strong>Tell us what you're interested in:</strong></p>
<dl>
    <dd><input type="radio" name="InterestedIn" value="BIBS<?php echo $_GET['InterestedIn'];?>"> Blow-In-Blanket System
    <input type="radio" name="InterestedIn" value="Foam<?php echo $_GET['InterestedIn'];?>"> Soya Spray Foam
    <input type="radio" name="InterestedIn" value="Attic<?php echo $_GET['InterestedIn'];?>"> Attic Insulation
    <input type="radio" name="InterestedIn" value="NotSure<?php echo $_GET['InterestedIn'];?>" checked="checked"> Not Sure</dd>
</dl>
<p><strong>Enter additional comments in the space provided below:</strong></p>
<dl>
    <dd><textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="5" border="0" id="comments"><?php echo $_GET['comments'];?></textarea></dd>
</dl>
<p><strong>Tell us how to get in touch with you:</strong></p>
<dl>
    <dd>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name*</td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="256" name="Name" value="<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company</td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="256" name="Company" value="<?php echo $_GET['company'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email*</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" maxlength="256" name="email" value="<?php echo $_GET['email'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" maxlength="256" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $_GET['phone'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" maxlength="256" name="City" value="<?php echo $_GET['city'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </dd>
</dl>
    <p><strong>Best method to get in touch with you:</strong></p>

<dl>
    <dd><input type="radio" name="ContactMethod" value="byphone<?php echo $_GET['InterestedIn'];?>" checked="checked">  Phone
    <input type="radio" name="ContactMethod" value="byemail<?php echo $_GET['InterestedIn'];?>"> Email
    </dd>
</dl>

   <dl><dd><img src="verificationimage.php?<?php echo rand(0,9999);?>" alt="verification image, type it in the box" width="50" height="24" align="top"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="verif_box" type="text" id="verif_box" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; width:80px; height:14px;"/><br /><br />
Enter Verification Image

</dd></dl>


<p style="padding-left:60px;"><input type="submit" class="button primary" value="Submit Form" name="submit"/>
<input type="reset" class="button primary" value="Clear Form" name"clear" /></p>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have a new baby at home and am very pressed for time being a new mom and trying to get this last project completed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you never populate the cookie and you should use a session anyway

Comment: @DaveRandom - since you helped me on the original form that I copied this one from, do you know why this one won't work? Am I missing something in the code? It looks identical to the other one I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some basic debugging would help a lot.

1. You seem to be mixing `$_GET` and a `method='post'`
2. Try a one line script that just does a call to `mail()` with hardcoded values.  Does that work?
3. Try submitting your form.  Output `$_POST`.  Does it have everything you were expecting?  Does `$_COOKIE`?
4. Construct all the strings you are passing into `mail` ahead of time.  Do they each look like they are supposed to?
5. Try taking those exact strings and putting them into `mail()` directly (like #2 above).  Does that work?

By the time you get to the end of this list, you'll know where the failure is and can get a much more specific answer.

Comment: php is my week point, could you possibly spell it out for me in lamens terms? I'm not sure how to check what you are suggesting. If I could get it to send, from there I can troubleshoot it to look the way I want in the email.